# SwiftUI render and layout in background or main thread?

Tags: swift, layout, swiftui, render

When working with List in SwiftUI, I found that it using UITableview. 
As I know, when layout, calculate row height, render UITableview (UIKit) make in main thread.
So My question is whether SwiftUI also layout in main thread too?

Comment: Yes, in main thread, and all actions (like with states) should be performed on main queue(thread).

Comment: Thanks sir,
Do you have any ref about it?